# Algorithm for arranging values in ascending order

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am currently making a piece of code that reads in up to 20 integers, assigns them to a vector, then arranges them in ascending order. I have everything, but I can not figure out how to arrange them in ascending order.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include "apvector.h"

void DisplayVector(int intOutputLoop, int intInputLoop, apvector<int> numbers);
void BuildVector(int &intInputLoop, apvector<int> &numbers);


void BuildVector(int &intInputLoop, apvector<int> &numbers)
{
    int intInput;

    do
    {
        if (!(cin >> intInput))
        {
            cout << "Please Enter A Numeric Value" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(1000000, '\n');
        }   
        else
        {
            if (intInput == 666)
                break;
            else
            {
                numbers[intInputLoop] = intInput;
                intInputLoop = intInputLoop + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    while (intInputLoop < 20);
}

void DisplayVector(int intOutputLoop, int intInputLoop, apvector<int> numbers)
{

}
int main()
{
    apvector<int> numbers(20);
    int intInputLoop = 0;
    int intOutputLoop = 0;

    BuildVector(intInputLoop, numbers);

    DisplayVector(intOutputLoop, intInputLoop, numbers);


}
```

Comment: It’s called sorting. There is `std::sort` in the standard library.

Comment: I tried that earlier, when I use it the code throws undefined identifier then underlines 'begin' how would I stop that?

Comment: @GregTheStudent it would help if you posted the code

Comment: Post your code. It may be as simple as adding some includes.

Comment: @GregTheStudent - Please post your [mcve] directly in this question, not offsite with a link.

Comment: Show the `apvector.h` file. `apvector` needs iterator access in order to work with `sort`.

Comment: Why use apvector when you have std vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with the following:

```
std::sort (numbers.begin(), numbers.end());

    for (std::vector<int>::iterator order = numbers.begin(); order != numbers.end(); ++order)
    {
            if (*order != 0)
                std::cout << ' ' << *order;
    }
```